# What is the difference between a 'Login' and an 'Interactive' bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface, bashrc

What is the difference between a ‘Login’ and an ‘Interactive’ bash shell?
I have quoted Wikipedia below but can anybody give a better answer?

EDIT: This is a community wiki so maybe rather than voting to close you could provide examples of which situations call for which type of $SHELL

> Startup scripts
>
> When Bash starts, it executes the
> commands in a variety of different
> scripts.
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive
> login shell, it first reads and
> executes commands from the file
> /etc/profile, if that file exists.
> After reading that file, it looks for
> ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
> ~/.profile, in that order, and reads
> and executes commands from the first
> one that exists and is readable.
>
> When a login shell exits, Bash reads
> and executes commands from the file
> ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not
> a login shell is started, Bash reads
> and executes commands from ~/.bashrc,
> if that file exists. This may be
> inhibited by using the --norc option.
> The --rcfile file option will force
> Bash to read and execute commands from
> file instead of ~/.bashrc.
>
> - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash#Startup_scripts)

Comment: I've edited the question to fit in more with the half arsed site rules. I don't think I'll ever understand the desire to delete useful information...

Comment: Why are people voting this question down? Seems perfectly legit to me?

Comment: Ugh, take the answer out of your question, and the post it as an answer. Its OK to answer your own question.

Comment: It's a very valid question as the distinction is confusing. Note for example that when you log in to a graphical environment via xdm and run xterm, you get an interactive shell and the login shell startup files aren't run.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your login shell's profile files you can set up some things that you will use during your session, and which only need to be done once. Some ideas:

- create a temporary file containing the IP address you connected from, later on you can include it in some scripts setting firewall rules.
- run ssh-agent, ask for your SSH keys, and store the SSH agent environment variables in a file.
- if that is a limited machine, and your co-workers want to be aware of each others logins, write(1) messages informing them of your login.

In a non-login shell's files (`.bashrc`) you should configure your shell:

- Fancy prompt
- set aliases
- set history options
- define custom shell functions
- export environment variables, (maybe PAGER, EDITOR if system-wide settings suck)
- load ssh-agent variables saved in `.bash_profile`

Usually, you would include `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` with the following. Then login shell gets all your customizations, and `.bash_profile` file does not have to duplicate things that are already in `.bashrc`.

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Is a login shell is the first one that starts when you're fresh on the machine? All other shells that you open after that may or may not be interactive. A shell that's running from cron? Doesn't seem interactive, but is it login? What if you're not on the machine? Those are the questions that are left unanswered

Comment: Now, THAT is an answer I can understand: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/difference-between-normal-shell-and-login-shell-14983/#post4828786